# How to trigger event stdin.on("data", [callback]) in the code?

Tags: node.js

Consider the following example

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) {
  console.log("recieved " + data)
})

process.stdin.write("foo\n")
process.stdin.write("bar\n")
```

When I type `something` in terminal, I get

```
 received something
```

Why it doesn't work in the same way for `foo` and `bar` which I sent earlier using `stdin.write`?

E.g. how can I trigger this event (`stdin.on("data)`) in the code? I was expected `process.stdin.write` to do this, but I'm just getting the same output back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a *Readable Stream* that gets its input from the `stdin` file descriptor. I don't think you can write into that descriptor (but you could connect it to another writable descriptor).

However, the easiest solution in your case it to just simulate the `'data'` events. Every stream is an EventEmiiter, so the following will work:

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.on("data", function(data) {
   console.log("recieved " + data)
});

process.stdin.emit('data', 'abc');
```

Comment: any way, to also capture a singular “shift” or „ctrl“ (with no other key)?